# Is it "be silent about" or "be silent on"?

Tags: prepositions

So I wonder if it is more natural, for US speakers, to say "The writing is silent about this possibility" or to say "The writing is silent on this possibility"?

Answer (score 4):

Either is correct and either is, I think, common. Personally, as a US speaker, I would prefer "silent on", although I would probably be more likely to use "silent as to" than either.

The google ngram viewer shows "silent on" as slightly more popular than "silent about", without much difference between British and American English.

American English:
[image: American English silent phrases]

British English:
[image]

Comment: An ngram comparing raw frequency is not going to show the contexts where the one or the other preposition is preferred.

Comment: Tᴚoɯɐuo: That's true, if context matters; I was taking the phrases to be equivalent. I see your answer, which is interesting. I'm not sure I would make the distinction you do. I suspect the rise of "about" is a result of the more literal/less idiomatic (in my opinion) "about" usage taking ground from "on" and "as to". At the very least the ngrams tell us there isn't a massive difference between US and British English (unless the typical context for silent is different and the preposition use is offsetting it).

Answer (score 2):

More correct would be :

> **"The writer is silent on the topic of"**

"Is silent about" is awkward; better is "remains silent about" or "silent as to". Silent in this case van often be replaced by the adjective "mute". "Silent" tends to create awkward sentences when used to describe one's nonverbal actions, but when used well can create an eloquent context, as it's uncommon and roundabout.

Answer (score 2):

We normally use **silent on** with the present tense to say that a *text* (or an author) doesn't address a particular topic in any way:

> The article is silent on the issue of trade imbalance.

whereas with **silent about** it is normal to use any tense, and the statement is normally made about people:

> The sellers had been silent about the zoning restrictions on the property.

I am qualifying these remarks with the word *normally* because you will surely find exceptions to this general trend. A careful writer, however, wouldn't use "silent about" in the text/author context, and in a conversation about some mundane transaction the more formal **silent on** is not likely to be used either.